# Slideshow function, stacked divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have been trying to use this fading slideshow code that I have found from this website.. http://blog.crondesign.com/2012/01/free-javascript-for-rotating-website.html

My main problem is that my divs  will not stack on top of each other and I have researched of different ways like z-indexing and position:absolute and none of them seem to work. Can someone please have a look at my code to see what isn't working!

HTML:

```
         <div id="slideshow_container">

                    <div id="banner2" class="banner"></div>

                    <div id="banner3" class="banner"></div>

                    <div id="banner4" class="banner"></div>

                    <div id="banner5" class="banner"></div>

                    <div id="banner1" class="banner"></div>

          </div>            

CSS

    #slideshow_container

    {
        height:486px;
        width: 806px;
        margin-top: 0%;
        margin:auto;
        background-color:green;
        display:block;
    }

    .banner
    {
        z-index:1;
        height:486px;
        width:806px;
        top:0px;
        background:#FFF;
        border:solid 1px #CCC
        position: absolute;
    }


    #banner1
    {
        background:green;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    #banner2
    {
        background: blue;
        z-index:6;
    }

    #banner3
    {
        background:#F90;
    }

    #banner4
    {
        background:#FFC;
    }
    #banner5
    {
        background:#99CCFF;
    }
    #slideshow_container
    {
        height:486px;
        width: 806px;
        margin-top: 0%;
        margin:auto;
        background-color:green;
        display:block;
    }

    .banner
    {
        z-index:1;
        height:486px;
        width:806px;
        top:0px;
        background:#FFF;
        border:solid 1px #CCC
        position: absolute;
    }


    #banner1
    {
        background:green;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    #banner2
    {
        background: blue;
        z-index:6;
    }

    #banner3
    {
        background:#F90;
    }

    #banner4
    {
        background:#FFC;
    }
#banner5
{
    background:#99CCFF;
}
```

Javascript

```
var imageCount = 5;  //how many images in total?
var changeSpeed = 3;  //how many seconds between fades?
var fadeSpeed = 0.5; //how many seconds should the fade take?
var fps = 25;  //animation frames per second

//BANNER FUNCTIONS:
var topImgID
var changeInterval

function $(id)
{ 
    return(document.getElementById(id));
}

function changeOpac(obj, opacity) 
{
    obj = obj.style; 
    obj.opacity = (opacity / 100);
    obj.MozOpacity = (opacity / 100);
    obj.KhtmlOpacity = (opacity / 100);
    obj.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity + ")";
}

function changeImage()
{
    var nextImgID = ( topImgID+1 <= imageCount ? topImgID+1 : 1 ); //get id number of next image in list
    var nextImg = $('banner'+nextImgID);
    var lastImg = $('banner'+topImgID);
    var opac = 0;
    changeOpac( nextImg, opac) //make next image invisible, then bring it to the top:
    lastImg.style.zIndex = 2;
    nextImg.style.zIndex = 3;

    var fadeInterval = setInterval(function()
    {
        if(opac < 100)
        {
            opac += Math.ceil(100/(fadeSpeed*fps));
            changeOpac(nextImg, opac);
        }
        else
        {
            lastImg.style.zIndex = 1;
            clearInterval(fadeInterval);
        }
    }, 1000/fps);

    topImgID = nextImgID;
}

function startBanner(firstImageID)
{
    topImgID = (firstImageID==undefined ? 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*(imageCount)) : firstImageID);
    $('banner'+topImgID).style.zIndex = 2;
    changeInterval = setInterval(changeImage, changeSpeed*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to close your `border` styles, so `position:absolute` isn't being read:

```
.banner
{
    z-index:1;
    height:486px;
    width:806px;
    top:0px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:solid 1px #CCC <----------- missing ';'
    position: absolute;
}
```